# PHP: regexp to replace partial text (comma) between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

can someone please provide me with a regexp which will replace a part of the text between parenthesis?

Example: I have the string

```
    123 (abc,def) 567
```

and I want to end up with

```
    123 (abc def) 567
```

So basically I want to replace the "," character in between parenthesis.

Thanks in advance, I seem to have forgotten most of what I knew about regular expressions.

Robert

Comment: Can there be more than one comma inside the parentheses, and you need to replace them all? If so, I don't think you can do this in one step. You have to pull out the text between parentheses, replace all the commas (with ordinary `str_replace`) and then replace that in the original string.

Comment: @user13955 Can there be recursive parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$s = '123 (abc,def) 567';

echo preg_replace('/(\([^)]*),([^)]*\))/', '$1 $2', $s);
```

Comment: Nope, should'nt. (),(zefzef) would be matched.

Answer (score 1):

A little clean, but simple.

```
<?php
$string = '123 (abc,def) 567';

$string = preg_replace('!,!',' ',$string);

echo $string;

?>
```

Output is:

```
123 (abc def) 567
```

As requested.

**Update**

To pacify the complaints another version would be:

```
$string = '123 (abc,def) 567';

$string = preg_replace('!([^,]+),(.+)!','$1 $2',$string);

echo $string;
```

**Another update indicating we're ONLY removing the comma between parenthesis**

```
$string = '123 (abc,def) 567';

$string = preg_replace('!(\([^,)]+),(.+\))!','$1 $2',$string);

echo $string;
```

**Not that this was the original question, to replace ALL commas between the parenthesis you can do it this way**

```
$strings = array('123 (abc,def) 567','(),(zefzef)','(,abc)','(def,hij,nop,abc),(abc,) 123');

foreach($strings as $string){
  echo "Before: $string = ";    
    while(preg_match('!(\([^,)]*),(.+\)?)!',$string)){
        $string = preg_replace('!(\([^,)]*),(.+\)?)!',"$1 $2",$string);
    }
  echo "After: $string\n";
}
```

Comment: This will replace commas outside the parentheses, too.

Comment: This doesn't check for the parentheses, and might as well just be `$string = str_replace(","," ",$string);`

Comment: @Barmar He didn't say that in his initial request. His mention of parenthesis is only an english description of what he wanted to happen.

Comment: @Kolink You can't assume that he'll be outputting anything that needs commas (like an array) based on the question. Thanks for the -1 for a correct answer though.

Comment: His question clearly says "replace a part of the text between parenthesis". The fact that his example doesn't have commas outside the parentheses doesn't negate this.

Comment: Try it with `$string = '1,23 (abc,def) 5,67';`

Comment: @Barmar if you need a Regex start your own question.

Comment: @Loamhoof [^,] covers parenthesis since they aren't commas.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 I'm just showing you a possible input, based on the question, where your answer gives the wrong result.

Comment: Since you use `+` instead of `*` in your latest update, it won't work if the comma is immediately after `(`. But that might never happen in practice, so it may be OK.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just answering the original question, not any derivatives that anyone who might also be answering might throw. If the original poster changes their question, then my answers will accommodate the original poster.

Comment: And I'm just critiquing on your answer based on the words in the original question, not assuming that the example is the only case he needs to deal with. Unfortunately, he hasn't come back to answer the questions some of have asked about the actual structure of the data.

Comment: @Barmar I'm saying this might be a string. He didn't clarify. All of my examples return the answer that he asked for.

Comment: @Barmar You didn't mention it, I've included a sample that replaces ALL commas inside of parenthesis.

Comment: @Loamhoof the last example (just added) does check for any commas between parenthesis... not that they asked.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
In case you have no recursive parenthesis, this would work like a charm:

```
/,(?=[^(]*?\))/
```

Of course replaced by a white space.

Comment: The `*` needs to be inside the grouping parentheses.

Comment: Yeah sure, anyway it wouldn't work if he can have recursive parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

This works in PHP. (if you can use preg_replace_callback):

```
 function commas($matches){return str_replace(',',' ',$matches[0]);}
 echo preg_replace_callback('/(\(.*\))/i','commas','123 (abc,def) 567');
```

or in one line:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(\(.*\))/i',create_function('$matches','return str_replace(","," ",$matches[0]);'),'123 (abc,def) 567');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Regular expression. This will help you.

```
,(?=[^\(]*\))
```

[Check demo](http://regex101.com/r/yY7xW5)